# Custom API in Elastic search

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

Building my first RESTful api, and thought I'd try elasticsearch for a base. Is there a way customize the API in Elasticsearch to only return certain fields from results of a query. For instance if I have data with fname, lname, city, state, zip, email and I only want to return a list of fnames and cities for every query matching the city field. So something like this:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/custom_call/_search" -d'
{
     "query": {
        "query_string": {
             "query": "Toronto",
             "fields": ["city"]
        }
     }
}'
```

Would ideally return something like:

```
{"took": 52, "timed_out": false, "_shards": {
    "total": 35,
    "successful": 35,
    "failed": 0
}, "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.375,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "persons",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "6",
            "_score": 0.375,
            "_source": {
                "fname": "Bob",
                "city": "Toronto",
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "persons",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "13",
            "_score": 0.375,
            "_source": {
                "fname": "Sue",
                "city": "Toronto",
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "persons",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "21",
            "_score": 0.375,
            "_source": {
                "fname": "Jose",
                "city": "Toronto",
            }
        }
    ]
}}
```

Not sure if Elasticsearch is set up to do this or even if you would want it to. My first foray into building a RESTful API. I figure if NPR StackOverflow like it, its worth a shot! Thanks for the help.

Comment: So the lesson to learn here is that if you are starting off learning something new to you and you have spent two weeks reading through documentation that pretty much everyone who uses elastic search admits is not ideal, you can expect snark and down voting even with details added to your question, and admission that you are just starting out. Maybe a meta comment but this kind of derision does not help people learn, merely provides an additional barrier to entry. I RTFM and was unclear, which is why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, I think you haven't tried to find out on your own.

Here is how to do that,

```
POST localhost:9200/index/type/_search 
{
   "query": {
    "query_string": {
         "query": "Toronto",
         "fields": ["city"]
    }
 },
   "_source" :["fields_you_want_to_get"]
}
```

The term you are looking is [source filtering.](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html)